# The variable seems to be independent, but the program works fine. why?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following library to give a update feature to my WordPress and this works fine with the code of documentation.

https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker/blob/master/README.md

```
require 'plugin-update-checker/plugin-update-checker.php';
$myUpdateChecker = Puc_v4_Factory::buildUpdateChecker(
    'https://github.com/user-name/repo-name/',
    __FILE__,
    'unique-plugin-or-theme-slug'
);
```

But I'm really wondering where this '$myUpdateChecker' variable came from and how this is working, because I can't find any part of the library's files using this variable.
It seems to be totally independent for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the variable right there. You can even name it something else if you want (eg. `$update_checker`), that shouldn't cause any issues in this particular case as the variable isn't being used anywhere else (according to your own words.)

For more details: [PHP variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I'm still wondering...

This variable seems to be just assigned the value and nothing else...
I want to know why the program works with this.
Without this variable, this library doesn't work.

Comment: The variable gets assigned an instance of the `Puc_v4p10_Plugin_UpdateChecker` object, the `Puc_v4p10_Theme_UpdateChecker` object, or the `Puc_v4p10_Vcs_BaseChecker` object (depends on your configuration). With it then you can then use the methods available to said instance (eg. `$update_checker->setAuthentication('your-token-here');`). In short, you need the variable if you're going to use any of these methods as mentioned on the readme.md file.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply and your time, what I got is '$update_checker' is a variable but at the same time is creating the instance of Puc_v4p10_Plugin_UpdateChecker Class. like 'new Puc_v4p10_Plugin_UpdateChecker'.